# Can i use amazon IAM as loging credentials for my apps users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to use the IAM API as a user registration service for my application.

I.e. if i present the user to create an account and password. Can they then log in with the IAM and use my application.

Or is it more for developers who are tinkering around with the actual AWS platform?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what AWS Identity and Access Management is made for. I guess you don't want your users to have access to your infrastructure … If you want an user registration you should implement it inside your application.

Comment: Thanks! I was just trying to be lazy haha oh well worth a shot!